# Sticky div starting at bottom of the page - stick to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a holding page for a website working as desired currently. Some Vegas running background fades and a simple nav bar down the bottom. Currently fixed to the bottom of the page with:

```
Position: absolute; bottom: 0;
```

View here: [www.gigabang.co](http://gigabang.co)

I would like to develop it so that the the sit loads to that page, then the user can scroll down to reveal content. The Footer would scroll with the page to reveal the content and then stick at the top of the page.

I have managed to rudimentarily implement some stickUp jQuery that gets the 'footer' to stick to the top of the page, but Ive had to remove the position: absolute to get it to function.

[Test Page](http://mark-chadwick.co.uk/gbngTEST.html)

Is there a way to get a div to start stuck to the bottom of the browser window and stick to the top after a scroll? Also ive had to remove the Vegas jQuery code to get the stickUp stuff to work too. Can anyone see why that would be?

Thanks for your help!
-m

stickUp Script:

```
<script src="gigabang/stickUp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
          //initiating jQuery
          jQuery(function($) {
            $(document).ready( function() {
              //enabling stickUp on the 'footer' class
              $('.footer').stickUp();
            });
          });

        </script>
```

Vegas Script:

```
<!--<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$.vegas('slideshow', {
delay: 8000,
backgrounds:[
{ src:'gigabang/WEBBG2.jpg', fade:1000 },
{ src:'gigabang/WEBBG5b.jpg', fade:1000 },
{ src:'gigabang/WEBBG6.jpg', fade:1000 },
{ src:'gigabang/WEBBG1.jpg', fade:1000 } ]
});$.vegas('overlay', {
src:'gigabang/vegas/overlays/13.png'
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Flex Property in css3 with align-content:flex-end.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

http://codepen.io/chrissp26/pen/xEAqC

### HTML

```
<h1>Footer Scroll</h1>
<footer id="footer">Footer</footer>
```

### CSS

```
body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Light", "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #999;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

footer {
  background: #008aca;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
}
```

### JS

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){

  sortTheFooterOut();

});

function sortTheFooterOut() {

  footer = $("#footer");

  $(window).on("scroll", function(){

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
      footer.addClass("fixed");
    } else {
      footer.removeClass("fixed");
    }

  });  
}
```

### Alternate JS with Animation

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){

  sortTheFooterOut();

});

function sortTheFooterOut() {

  footer = $("#footer");

  $(window).on("scroll", function(){

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {

      if (!footer.hasClass("fixed")) {
      footer.fadeOut(250,function(){

        footer.addClass("fixed").fadeIn(250);

      });
      }
    } else {
      footer.fadeOut(250,function(){

        footer.removeClass("fixed").fadeIn(250);

      });
    }

  });  
}
```

Comment: Ooh! Almost. But I'd prefer it to scroll up the page with the content rather than just switch from bottom to top.

Comment: Initially positioning the element with position absolute removes it from the flow of the page which is effectively preventing it from scrolling to the top. You would have to animate or transition the element from the bottom of the page to the top.

Comment: I've added an animation example as well.

Comment: Cheers for your help so far... Theres no way to position a div at the bottom of the browser without using absolute positioning as far as I know is there...?

Comment: You can't have it flow with the content and sit at the bottom because the absolute positioning will remove it from the flow. You would have to place it inline with the content on the page like the header in this example: http://codepen.io/chrissp26/pen/wfsvy

Comment: Got it! Not exactly how I was intending to do it, but actually works really well I think...
http://mark-chadwick.co.uk/gbngTEST2.html